# How to fix the exclamation mark in Product structured data markup?

Tags: json, search-engine, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

I prepared a Product Schema for my website and while I tested it with Google **Structured Data Testing Tool** It showing two exclamation symbols on the left side of the testing tool. Does it makes any problem? How to fix it?

[image]

I copied the schema from one of the site of mine which already using Product Schema. On that site its working fine without any warring messages.

```
        <script type="application/ld+json">
        {
        "@context":"https://schema.org/",
        "@type":"Product",
        "@id":"12456",
        "name":"Product Name",
        "offers":[{"@type":"Offer",
        "url":"http://www.example.com",
        "priceCurrency":"QAR",
        "availability":"https://schema.org/inStock",
        "sku":"KK145",
        "image":"http://www.example.com/image1.jpg",
        "description":"ABC ABCD ABCD",
        "seller":{"@type":"Organization",
        "name":"EXAMPLE CO WLL",
        "url":"https://example.com"},
        "price":"1500>"}
        ]}
        </script>
```

Comment: They correspond to warnings listed in the right sidebar. Each warning has this exclamation mark, too. If you click the warning, it hightlights the line in the left sidebar.

Comment: Does it cause problem or just a warring massage?

Comment: Errors mean that you won’t get the rich result in Google Search, warnings mean that you won’t get the best variant of the rich result (and maybe lessen the chance to get it in the first place, not sure, though)